# bash script won't execute terminal command

Tags: bash, shell

I have written a simple bash script shown below:

```
#!/bin/bashhere
/net/account/admin/george.chilumbu/nmon2influxdb import /data1/nmon/log-file.nmon
```

But when i execute the script, i get the following error message

```
2016/05/25 18:05:18 TimeStamp T0007 not found
```

However, when i try to run the command directly in the terminal, it runs just fine. Not sure what is the issue here. I even tried putting the command in a function and then calling that function, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: you are probably relying in some variables defined in your current session, that are not available when running the script.

Comment: So how would i go about running this command using a cron job and still utilizing the session that apparently is allowing the command to execute directly in the terminal but not in a script?

Comment: Passing the parameters.

Comment: Huh? That looks like a `bashhere` script more than a `bash` script.